# jQuery Plugin variable undefined

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-plugins, undefined

I am working on creating my first jQuery based plugin but I am stuck at an issue.

I receive an error stating var minHeight is undefined when I am trying to console.log it.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.ezToggle = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            selector: $('.selector'),
            minHeight: defaults.selector.height(),
            speed: 200
        }
        console.log(defaults.minHeight); // appears undefined       
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selector in attribute minHeight too:

```
minHeight: $('.selector').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to check that selector is defined.